# How to stop an instance of GCDWebUploader - Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcdwebserver

In my app I have successfully started an instance of GCDWebUploader and I can upload files into my App's documents directory.
What I would like is to give the users the ability to stop the web sever whenever a button is pressed.

I've tried to set the instance to nil but this has no effect. Does there is a way to do this ? I've looked into the GCDWebUploader's header files but with no success !

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GCDWebUploader` subclasses `GCDWebServer`, so be sure to also look for methods in the super class. The one you would likely want is `-stop`.

Comment: How could I've forgotten to look at it ! Thanks for you help :)